Как в форме отличить создание объекта от редактирования?
Мне нужно скрывать или делать неактивными часть элементов формы в случае, если объект только создается. Как понять что мы редактируем а не создаем объект?

Можно проверить, что объект существует в базе.
Для этого можно воспользоваться оператором PREV.
Условие проверки такое: PREV(o IS ClassName).

o - это имя объекта в форме
ClassName - его класс.

Это выражение будет истинно, если объект записан в базу данных.
